# Required Fields and Redirects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, webforms

I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the Submit button, they are redirected to another page. Addittionally, if they try submitting without entering their first name, last name, or email, it will return an error saying "This is a required field". For some reason, neither of this are working. Nothing happens when submit is clicked. I am sure it is something simple but I have never worked with these scripts before so I don't know what I am looking for.

Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <button><input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit();"/></button><br>
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" required/><br>
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input class="lname" type="text" required/><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input class="email" type="text" required/><br>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="yes" id="yes" />
            <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="file" value="no" id="no" />
            <label for="No">No</label><br>
            <p><input type="file" size="30" required></p>
</form>

        <script>
            function submit() {
                window.location= "http://stackoverflow.com"
            }
        </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" required /><br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="lname" type="text" required/><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="email" type="text" required/><br>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="yes" id="yes" />
        <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="no" id="no" />
        <label for="No">No</label><br>
        <p><input type="file" size="30" required></p>
</form>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
      window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That did it! I had to add https:// to make it link to the actual page but other than that it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Quick way as it looks like your not using ajax.

Remove the onclick from the submit button (require tag is being ignored because of this) along with the JavaScript and return a 302 redirect with the url from the server if it's successful.